infringement scenario
Let suppose that A happening and B happening are entirely independent
claim 1:
identity a winner on a condition of A happening;
claim 2:
identity a winner on a condition of A happening or B happening;
claim 3:
identity a winner on a condition of A happening;
identity a winner on a condition of B happening;
Questions:

Does claim 2 infringe upon claim 1?
Does claim 3 infringe upon claim 1?
Does it matter or not whether A happening and B happening are entirely independent, partially dependent, or fully dependent?


To keep terminology straight, claims do not infringe claims. Products that are made, sold, offered for sale, used or imported are the only things that can infringe claims.


Does [performance of] claim 2 infringe upon claim 1?

Assuming these are method claims, I would say performance of claim 2 infringes on claim 1 in those instances when A happened and not in those instances when only B happened.

Does [performance of] claim 3 infringe upon claim 1?

Assuming claim 1 is a "comprising" claim, I would say yes.

Does it matter or not whether A happening and B happening are entirely independent, partially dependent, or fully dependent?

Probably not.
